# Clarifying the German Academic Ranks

Tags: noun

I presently wish to understand more fully the literal meaning, etymology, or grammatical features of the ranks used in German academia [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_ranks):

- **Hilfassistent/innen**: Undergraduate research assistant / Undergraduate teaching assistant
- **Assistent/innen**: research assistant (typically a PhD student)
- **Wissenschaftliche Mitarbeiter/innen**: Scientific Staff (synonymous with "Assistent/innen")
- **Postdoc**: Postdoc (i.e., after PhD)
- **Oberassistent/innen**: senior researcher/lecturer (typically after 1–2 years as a postdoc)
- **Lehrbeauftragte**: lecturer / adjunct professor
- **Gastdozent/innen**: visiting lecturer
- **Assistenzprofessor**: assistant professor (requires PhD)
- **Privatdozent/innen**: senior lecturer (has the habilitation but not professorship)
- **Professor**: full professor (ordinary and extraordinary)

Comment: Just to make sure: You are asking this about Germany, not German speaking countries in general? There will be differences. A quick Google search for *Oberassistent* only turned up positions in Switzerland, I am not sure whether it is an official job description in Germany.

Comment: I am asking about German speaking countries in general since I am interested in the language, I apologize. Although now that you mention this I realize I also wish to know about Germany specifically. I assumed these positions may have been unique to or created in Germany.

Comment: Regarding your bold stems: The male/female are Assistent and Assistentin, Dozent and Dozentin. So female is only the "-in".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with the structure of an organization in the nation called *Germany*. It doesn't deal with the language called *German*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, I agree that the question is not very clear on that, but it seems to be actually also about the words, their origin and grammatical structure.

Comment: I am willing to edit my question for clarity if this is required. Thank you very much for all these clarifications!

Comment: If the community votes accept @HubertSchölnast 's opinion, then your question is off-topic here. But, you can re-ask this on the http://academia.stackexchange.com, there it would be ontopic.

Comment: I do not think that the question would be a good fit for Academia in its current form since it’s far too broad. Some of the sub-questions are a good fit for Academia; others are a good fit for this site, but they should be asked separately.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Then, are you able to help me determine my individual questions with their apropriate stack? And in how long will this vote be cast.

Comment: @aitía: It depends a bit on what you already know and is subject to Meta discussion, as already noted. As preliminary rule of thumb, I would say: If you want to understand a word’s literal meaning, etymology, or grammatical features ask here (keep in mind to tell us what you already know/found). If you want to understand the duties, privileges, … of a particular academic rank, ask on Academia.

Comment: Note that your edit does not address the problem of broadness. You can ask a separate question here (and on Academia) regarding each rank – if whatever you are asking for cannot be easily answered by a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my experience from three german universities and one german research institution:

- **Hilfswissenschaftler (HiWi)**: This is an undergraduate research assistant or an undergraduate teaching assistant. In my contracts, always the term **studentische Hilfskraft** was used. The term *Hilfsassistent* is not familiar to me, but I would understand what you mean. However, also see the term *Assistent* below.
- **wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter**: This is a collective term for all the scientific staff that is working within a defined group or area, *including*

  - **Doktorand**: Ph.D. student
  - **PostDoc**: postdoc

  but *excluding* the

  - **Privatdozent**: Someone who is habilitated but not a professor.
  - **Professor**: Professor
- **Lehrbeauftragter**: lecturer

There are some special forms, such as **Akademischer Rat**, **Hochschulprofessor**, **Juniorprofessor** and others.

The term **Oberassistent** is entirely unfamiliar to me. In my current institution and the nearby university hospital, **Assistent** always exclusively refers to assisting staff, such as a medical technical assistant, a laboratory assistent, or [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_laboratory_scientist).

---

Apart from this, you can usually append the postfix *in* to obtain the female forms: Dozent*in*, Assistent*in*, Professor*in*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For words derived from Latin, *-en* is the plural suffix. In general, *-in* is used for a specifically female form, with plural *-innen*.

Origins:

The Latin verb *assistere* "to stand by, to help", literally "to stand next to", has the present participle *assistens* which becomes *assistent-* in all forms except nominanitive. From this derives the English word *assist**a**nt* (with a spelling change) and the German word *Assistent*, "someone who helps". The corresponding native German word is *Mitarbeiter*, which derives from the verb *mitarbeiten* "work together".

So a professor had someone to help him, which would be an older student, and that ossified into a position for graduate students called "Assistent" or "wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter" to make it clear it's about assisting in research, and not in manual labor etc. The prefix "Hilfs-" is "auxiliary" in English, so an undergraduate student helping in research or teaching would become a "Hilfsassistent". Another word for that is "Hilfswissenschaftler" or short "Hiwi".

"Ober-" indicates superior rank (literally "ober" = above), and is also frequently used in other german compounds. In practice, I've never heard the term "Oberassistent".

The Latin word *docere* "to teach" forms German *Dozent* in the same way as above, with a spelling change to adapt to German orthography. "Gast" is a visitor, so a "Gastdozent" is a "visiting" scientist who also teaches during his stay.

"Privat" means "on one's own, not in official capacity", so a "Privatdozent" is someone who has no "official" position, because he is (not yet) a professor.

"Lehrbeauftragter" means "someone who has been appointed (beauftragt) to teach (lehren)", so that is anyone who holds lectures and teaches, but doesn't hold one of the other titles.

As for usage, see the other answer.

Comment: Was meinst du bei Privatdozent mit _has no "official" position_? Bei uns haben alle Privatdozenten eine feste Stelle. Vielleicht meinst du aber etwas anderes?